# How do I index list elements in For loop in Mathematica?

Tags: for-loop, syntax, wolfram-mathematica, notation

I do not know the required syntax in Mathematica for printing out multiple 3D plots as intended in the following code.

```
For[i = 1, i <= accBeta + 1, i++,
    ListPlot3D[p3[[All, i]], PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
]
```

Here p3 is a list of lists containing the information while i is my counting index. This doesn't run into errors, but the input is simply ignored. Can you help me out on this issue?

Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some example data

```
p3 = Table[Sin[k j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {k, 3}];
```

The following are equivalent

```
Table[ListPlot3D[p3[[x]], Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], {x, Length[p3]}]

Map[ListPlot3D[#, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0,
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &, p3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a `For` loop here. For instance you could use `Table`:

```
Table[ListPlot3D[p3[[All,i]]], {i, 1, accBeta+1}]
```

That should print your plots. Hope that's helpful.

There are many related questions on the [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) - typically the answer is not to use a `For` or `Do` loop :)